# Moq error System.InvalidProgramException : Cannot create boxed ByRef-like values

Tags: c#, moq

Getting below issue in MOQ unit test after upgrading the framework from 3.1 to 6.

Message:

```
System.InvalidProgramException : Cannot create boxed ByRef-like values.
Stack Trace: 
StreamProxy.Write(ReadOnlySpan`1 buffer)
StreamWriter.Flush(Boolean flushStream, Boolean flushEncoder)
StreamWriter.Flush()
```

Test Code: (Same code is working fine in .net core 3.1 but failing with exception in .net 6)

```
public void StreamWriter_Test()
{
var stream = new Mock<Stream>();
stream.Setup(s => s.CanWrite).Returns(true);
using var sw = new StreamWriter(stream.Object);
sw.WriteLine("Test");
sw.Flush();
}
```

Note: If i remove line "sw.WriteLine("Test");" from the code then everything works fine.

Comment: Did you mean `new Mock<Stream>()`, by any chance?

Comment: I’d just use a memory stream in this case

Comment: @JeroenMostert, Yes it is "new Mock<Stream>()", have updated it now, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @DanielA.White, Using memory stream giving the same error.

Comment: Are you using `Mock<MemoryStream>` or `MemoryStream`? Daniel is alluding to the latter -- you don't actually need a dynamically generated mock in this case, a concrete class behaving as one would serve just as well. The main problem is that the new framework is using the `ReadOnlySpan` overloads of the methods, which cannot be mocked (by Moq, at least).

Comment: @JeroenMostert, thanks for the explanation, i understand that we cannot mock stream after framework upgrade, now the issue i have is, in my method i am writing data to stream and i need to verify that in my unit test, before framework upgrade i was verifying the same as "stream.Verify(s => s.Write(It.IsAny<byte[]>(), It.IsAny<int>(), It.IsAny<int>()), Times.AtLeastOnce());"

Now if i do not mock the stream how i can verify if data is written to stream or not in my unit test ?

Comment: Just read the memory stream. You shouldn’t have to test streamwriter

Comment: @DanielA.White, Issue here is i am creating a memory stream in my test method while streamwriter is created in my original method logic, in which i am flushing the streamwriter object, so i am not able to read the stream that i have passed from my unit test...

Comment: Please post that as a new question. More context the better

Comment: Verifying that `.Write` is called "at least once" is a very weak test to begin with. If you need to verify data is written correctly, you want to verify what's ultimately written to the stream when all is said and done, regardless of how many calls that took, or exactly which overload of `.Write` was used. `MemoryStream` can serve that purpose perfectly well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem found is, new framework is using the ReadOnlySpan overloads of the methods, which cannot be mocked by Moq at present.

So i have used memory stream instead of Mock.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).